# Delete tables with Partitions in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset that has a few different tables in it. For one of the tables, it has 100 partitions. I would like to drop/delete all the partitions of a table with a specific name.

For example, I have the below in one dataset. So far, I can only delete a partition at a time. Is there anyway for me to delete all all TableA partitions?

```
tableA_20161220
tableA_20161221
tableA_20161223
tableB_20161220
tableB_20161221
tableB_20161223
```

Answer (score 2):

As Mikhail has already pointed out, you write a script using the API.

We regularly use the CLI for such tasks. This little snippet should be enough to get you going. Just be careful using it because it performs a '**force**' delete i.e. no confirmation:

```
bq ls --format=csv <DATASET> | awk '{if(NR>1)print}' | awk -F, '{print $1}' | grep 'A' | xargs -n 1 -P 4 -i bq rm -f <DATASET>.{}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly modified version of what Graham has provided.

```
bq ls <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET> | grep "<SHARDED_TABLE_NAME>" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs "-I%" bq rm -f <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET>."%"
```

Explaining this script,

1.List all the tables in the dataset

```
bq ls <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET>
```

2.Filter the dataset that has the sharded tables.

```
grep "<SHARDED_TABLE_NAME>"
```

3.Print just the first column(the tables in the dataset)

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

4.For each table in the output, perform the delete operation

```
xargs "-I%" bq rm -f <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET>."%"
```

More on `xargs` [here](https://shapeshed.com/unix-xargs/) and more on bq command line [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool)

The solution to your problem will be,

```
bq ls <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET> | grep "tableA" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs "-I%" bq rm -f <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET>."%"
```

And as Graham had already mentioned, be careful about the dataset you are deleting.

Answer (score 0):

From the Web UI you can delete only one table at a time.

Overall, BigQuery [tables.delete](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/delete) API accepts only one table at a time

Using [client of your choice](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) or [command line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool) you can "script" to make this process fully or semi-automated to delete needed tables in a loop.